# Android - Device not detected

Tags: android

I'm trying to test an Android Application on my Galaxy Nexus (from Google). I use Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit and Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

My device doesn't show in Eclipse DDMS view. My device also doesn't show when I run **adb devices** in cmd.

I have USB debugging enabled.

When I try to install the USB driver as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)  I get a message that my device software is up to date.

I also tried killing the adb server and starting it again.

Comment: Have you tried removing the device from Device Manager first and then plugging in the device again to reinstall the drivers from their cached install location? Simply checking for a better driver does not repair a faulty driver.

Comment: @KrofDrakula yes I tried that, not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the [Universal Naked Driver](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1379875) a try? Be sure to follow the steps in the forum post.

Comment: when I remove the old driver, I can't find my phone in device manager, if I scan for hardware changes, or unplug it and plug it in again, the default driver installs again.

Comment: Did you reboot after uninstalling from device manager? Once windows has restarted, it will probably try to install the drivers. You might be able to specify a driver before then but if not maybe you can click "Update Driver" for the device.

Comment: Yes I did. Restart the PC, restart the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus devices require the [Google USB Drivers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html), you can get them through the SDK Manager.

If you have them installed and the device still is not detected try the following:

- Use a different USB port (for me the USB 3.0 port is always making problems)
- Restart the device and the computer
- Restart ADB

Also take a look [here](http://nexusshacks.com/nexus-s-hacks/how-to-install-nexus-s-windows-usb-drivers/), which explains how to install drivers for the Nexus S.

Comment: I tried restart! I tried every USB port (I have 3xUSB3.0 and 1xUSB 2.0).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I could not get my device to show up in my Eclipse devices window. When I typed `adb devices`, no devices were discovered. Fortunately, I discovered [this](http://theunlockr.com/2009/10/06/how-to-set-up-adb-usb-drivers-for-android-devices/) website. It basically had me install a generic driver for my Motorola (Android 2). It had other drivers for Samsung and other manufacturers. After the install, my Motorola phone became visible with ADB.